# How to pass date of birth to database in Laravel?

Tags: php, database, laravel, date

I am making signup form in which I am taking date of birth from user but I do not know how to pass it to database.

```
<div class="form-group row">
<label for="dob" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
{{ __('DOB') }}</label>
<div class="col-md-6 input-group input-group-sm col-4 m-0 ">
<input type="date" name="dob" style="width: 200px;" class="form-control {{ 
$errors->has('date') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="date" placeholder="" 
required/>
@if ($errors->has('date'))
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
<strong>{{ $errors->first('date') }}</strong>
</span>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you need to create a valid formular first, I show you a very basic example you have to adept that yourself!

The view would look something like this:

A form which posts the data in this case date_of_birth after clicking on the submit button to this url `/post/store`

```
<form action="/post/store" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="text" name="date_of_birth">
    <button class="button" type="submit">
</form>
```

The route should look something similiar to this:

This route call the store function of the PostController

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'post', 'as' => 'post.'], function () {
    // ...
    Route::post('store', ['as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'PostController@store']);
});
```

In your PostController to get the request from the formular and create a new Post.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        Post::create([
            // ... add your other data
            'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth
        ]);

        return redirect()->route('/');
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add the new data in your model's fillable array:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'date_of_birth'
];
```

I expect you to aleady have a proper migration.

I advice you to have a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers), becasue this is pretty basic stuff